# Update records in Postgres from a select query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am having 2 tables in PostgreSQL, have to fetch total records from both table . If count > 50 then update status=5 of oldest record. Here is query for oldest record. Have to update oldest record in single query. Here is query I have tried to find oldest record

```
 (select   'SPORTS' AS eventType,activity.articleId,activity.title,activity.articleText,
           activity.createdDate,activity.creatorscreenname as creatorScreenNameStr
  FROM     SPORTS activity
  where    activity.status=1
  and      activity.createdBy=101
  order by createdDate ASC limit 1)
 UNION
 (select   'MUSIC' AS musicType,activity.wikiTopicId as articleId,
           activity.title as title,activity.problemDescription as articleText,
           activity.createdDate,activity.creatorScreenName as creatorScreenNameStr
  FROM     MUSIC activity
  where    activity.status=1
  and      activity.createdBy=101
  order by createdDate ASC limit 1)
 ORDER BY 5 ASC limit 1
```

Comment: limit 1will never return 50 records

Comment: i am looking for only oldest record.

Comment: Consider breaking down your problem into several queries and combine them in a plpgsql DO block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up next example:

> ```
> create table sports(id int, status int, createdBy int, createdDate date);
> create table music(id int, status int, createdBy int, createdDate date);
> insert into sports values (1, 1, 101, '20170101'), (2, 2, 101, '20170102'), (3, 1, 102, '20170103');
> insert into music  values (1, 1, 101, '20170201'), (2, 2, 101, '20170202'), (3, 1, 102, '20170203');
> ```

> ```
> with sel as
> (
>     select ttype, id, status, createdBy, createdDate
>     from 
>         (
>         (select 'sports' as ttype, id, status, createdBy, createdDate
>         from   sports
>         where  status = 1
>         and    createdBy = 101
>         order  by createdDate
>         limit  1)
>         union
>         (select 'music' as ttype, id, status, createdBy, createdDate
>         from   music
>         where  status = 1
>         and    createdBy = 101
>         order  by createdDate
>         limit  1)
>         ) un
>     order by 5
>     limit 1
> )
>     , updsport as
>     (
>         update sports
>         set    status = 5
>         from   sel
>         where  sports.id = sel.id
>         and    sel.ttype = 'sports'
>     )
>     update music
>     set    status = 5
>     from   sel
>     where  music.id = sel.id
>     and    sel.ttype = 'music'
>     ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from sports order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | status | createdby | createddate
> -: | -----: | --------: | :----------
>  1 |      5 |       101 | 2017-01-01 
>  2 |      2 |       101 | 2017-01-02 
>  3 |      1 |       102 | 2017-01-03
> ```

> ```
> select * from music order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | status | createdby | createddate
> -: | -----: | --------: | :----------
>  1 |      1 |       101 | 2017-02-01 
>  2 |      2 |       101 | 2017-02-02 
>  3 |      1 |       102 | 2017-02-03
> ```

Now try by changing `createdDate` on sports or music table just to change the filter criteria.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=bd24c422029a3a38e806c3a7bc9d8131)*